# Nativescript Listview with header and scroll entire page

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using ListView with Header portion on top of it like below,

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout height="200">
    <Label text="Header content goes in this section"></Label>
  <StackLayout>
  <ListView [items]='posts'>
   <!-- template items goes here --> 
  </ListView>   
</StackLayout>
```

When we scroll to list the header is sticky in this case.
Is there a option that scroll overrides header also ?.I mean that header also part of scroll.

Comment: Try Scrollview instead of top most StackLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fr Angular-2 application you can now use tkTemplateKey deirective and create your own headers, footers, groups and other custom list-view elements.
Example can be found [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/common-screens/lists/multi-line-grouped.html#multi-line-grouped.)

Here is the code for a list-view with header and groups.

***page.component.html***

```
<ListView [items]="countries" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" (itemTap)="onItemTapFirstList($event)" class="list-group" separatorColor="white">
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="header" let-header="item">
        <Label [text]="header.name" class="list-group-item h3 bg-primary" isUserInteractionEnabled="false" color="white" fontSize="24"></Label>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="footer" let-footer="item">
        <Label [text]="footer.name" class="list-group-item" backgroundColor="gray"></Label>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="cell" let-country="item">
        <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
            <Label [text]="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading"></Label>
            <Label [text]="country.desc" class="list-group-item-text" textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

***page.component.ts***

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./multi-line-grouped.component.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MultiLineGroupedListViewExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    public countries: Array<any> = [];

    public templateSelector = (item: any, index: number, items: any) => {
        return item.type || "cell";
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        for (let i = 0; i < mockedCounties.length; i++) {
            this.countries.push(mockedCounties[i]);
        }
    }

    onItemTapFirstList(args: ItemEventData) {
        console.log(args.index);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error that let is only supported on ng-template not template!

Comment: ^^^ You are right! I've updated the snippet to use `ng-template` as this the way to do it now in Angular

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's another way, but one way could be moving the header inside the listview. For that to work it needs to be in the posts Array, so you may want to transform that into some sort of wrapping class that can contain eiter a header or item row. Then create two templates inside the listview that depending on the template key render a header or an item.

For details on templates, see https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/list-view#define-multiple-item-templates-and-an-item-template-selector-in-xml

Comment: is the template feature relatively new in {N} (not Angular)? Never seen it before. I'm using RadListView - will this syntax work in RLV? I'm not doing anything fancy in RLV - any reason not to use basic {N} ListView (i.e. over RLV)?

Comment: Since 2.4-ish. You can use basic LV if you don't need the added sugar.

Answer (score -1):

You can use *ngFor creating the list.Here is the sample code for doing this.

```
 <ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>
  //define your header over here
  <Label text="hey header"></Label>
   <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of <Array>">
    <GridLayout columns="4*,*" rows="*,">
         <Label  row="0" col="0" text="hey label"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
   <StackLayout>
  <StackLayout>
 </ScollView>
```

Comment: this is very inefficient.